# TekPub Feedback

Tags: design

Following on from a previous thread that had a link to TekPub, I have just had a quick look and I think it looks pretty impressive.  Are any of you guys subscribers and if so would you recommend it?  I am mainly interested in general software design and, as a language, C# and it's features.  Is there much content posted on a regular basis along these lines to warrant the outlay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, I would get it.  For the small amount of money a month that it costs, you really can't beat what's on there. They have top notch people making the videos, and there is a load of content.  What's nice is that

1. They add new content (they just add Mastering C# by Jon Skeet).
2. If at some point in time you don't get any more value, you can always cancel.

We use it where I work to get people to pick up things they need to learn (we have several people who are just starting out on C# etc.).  It honestly makes my life a lot easier, because I can have them watch it instead of creating presentations to teach them things they need to know.  This sounds lazy, but I can honestly say from experience that it takes a lot of time to create a presentation to show a topic which gets people to understand concepts like programming.

This isn't also just for beginning people, they have a number of more advanced topics as well (multithreading etc.).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to get a recurring subscription if you're not satisfied with the amount of new material produced. You can always purchase the productions you are interested in individually.

Answer (score 1):

They go to great lengths to ensure customers are satisfied with the content. If you don't like the content, you can tell them at any time and they will give you a refund.

I was a monthly subscriber for about 6 months, then upgraded to a yearly subscription b/c it's really worth it. The content is good, fresh, and new stuff is coming out on a regular basis. Plus, every single episode is done by well-known experts of the topic. I can't think of many other training sites where I recognize almost every video author's name (except maybe Pluralsight).

Answer (score 1):

I subscribe to TekPub. I like it very much as I travel a lot, and carrying books is heavy and is expensive. Having access to videos to watch/download is super awesome. I totally recommend them.

The quality of the videos have been pretty good. I've gone through Git, Rails 3, and started a few others recently. They come out with new series and/or add to an existing one almost every month. You can follow them on twitter too at: [@tekpub](http://twitter.com/tekpub) to follow updates almost in real time.

Other services you may want to look at are:

- [PeepCode](http://www.peepcode.com) (their library of videos is bigger than TekPub's)
- [ontwik](http://ontwik.com/) (they do push out quite a few videos a month)